Gaussian line integral over a polygon
Problem definition
Let $y=z+v$, where $z$ is uniformly distributed over the contour of a polygon with vertices $V_1,\dots,V_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $v\sim\mathcal{N}(0,R)$. Let $\ell$ be the set of points occupied by the polygon contour, then the density of $z$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
p_z(z;\ell)=\frac{1_\ell(z)}{|\ell|}
\end{equation}
where $1_\ell(z)$ gets unitary value if $z\in \ell$ and null value otherwise, while $|\ell|\triangleq\int 1_\ell(\zeta)\,\mathrm{d}\zeta$ is the length of the polygon contour (with the convention $V_{n+1}\triangleq V_1$). Independence between $z$ and $v$ allows to write the PDF of $y$ as the convolution
\begin{equation}
p_y(y;\ell)=\int p_z(z;\ell)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z;0,R)\,\mathrm{d}z=
\int p_z(z;\ell)\,\mathcal{N}(z;y,R)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
my problem consists of solving this integral.
A first solution
The polygon contour $\ell$ can be partitioned as the union of its edges $\ell_i\triangleq(V_i, V_{i+1})$. Accordingly, the PDF of $z$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
p_z(z;\ell)= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{|\ell_i|}{|\ell|} \underbrace{\frac{1_{\ell_i}(z)}{|\ell_i|}}_{\triangleq p_z(z;\ell_i)}
\end{equation}
which is a mixture of uniform distributions over the polygon edges $\ell_i$. Using this decomposition, the PDF of $y$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p(y; \ell)&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{|\ell_i|}{|\ell|}\int p_z(z; \ell_i)\,\mathcal{N}(z; y, R)\,\mathrm{ d}z\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{|\ell_i|}{|\ell|}\int \frac{1_{\ell}(z)}{|\ell_i|}\,\mathcal{N}(z; y, R)\,\mathrm{ d}z\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now, using the parametrization
\begin{equation}
z(\lambda)=(V_{i+1}-V_i)\lambda+V_i\qquad \lambda\in[0,1]
\end{equation}
it follows
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p(y; \ell)
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{|\ell_i|}{|\ell|}\int \frac{1_{\ell}(z(\lambda))}{|\ell_i|}\,\mathcal{N}(z(\lambda); y, R)\, \lVert \dot{z}(\lambda)\rVert\,\mathrm{ d}\lambda\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{|\ell_i|}{|\ell|} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \mathcal{N}(z(\lambda); y, R)\,\,\mathrm{ d}\lambda}_{\triangleq p_y(y;\ell_i)}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where it was observed that $1_\ell(z(\lambda))=1_{[0,1]}(\lambda)$ and $\lVert \dot{z}(\lambda)\rVert=|\ell_i|$ (with $\dot{z}$ being the derivative wrt $\lambda$). At this point, after some algebra, $p_y(y;\ell_i)$ can be expressed in a closed form by employing the standard CDF.
A second solution
The polygon line $\ell$ can be parametrized as follows,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
z(\lambda) &= (V_{\lfloor n\lambda\rfloor+2}-V_{\lfloor n\lambda \rfloor+1})\{n\lambda\}+V_{\lfloor n\lambda \rfloor+1}
\end{aligned}
\qquad \lambda \in [0,1]
\end{equation}
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\leq x$ and $\{x\}\triangleq x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$. This parametrization seems complex, but actually is just a compact expression of the piece-wise linear function
\begin{equation}
z(\lambda)\triangleq \begin{cases}
(V_{2}-V_{1})(n\lambda-0/n)+V_1 & \text{if } \lambda \in[0/n,1/n) \\
(V_{3}-V_{2})(n\lambda-1/n)+V_2 & \text{if } \lambda \in[1/n,2/n) \\
\hfil\vdots\hfil & \hfil\vdots\hfil \\
(V_{i+2}-V_{i+1})(n\lambda-(i-1)/n)+V_{i+1} & \text{if } \lambda \in[(i-1)/n,i/n) \\
\hfil\vdots\hfil & \hfil\vdots\hfil \\
(V_{1}-V_{n})(n\lambda-1/n)+V_{n} & \text{if } \lambda \in[(n-1)/n,n/n] \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Accordingly, the density of $y$ gets the form
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
p_y(y;\ell)&= \int \frac{1_{\ell}(z(\lambda))}{|\ell|} \mathcal{N}(z(\lambda);y,R)\,\lVert \dot{z}(\lambda)\rVert\mathrm{d}\lambda= 
\frac{1}{|\ell|}\int_0^1 \mathcal{N}(z(\lambda);y,R)\,\lVert \dot{z}(\lambda)\rVert \mathrm{d}\lambda\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{|\ell_i|}{|\ell|} \underbrace{\,n\,\int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}} \mathcal{N}(z(\lambda); y, R)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda}_{\triangleq \tilde{p}_y(y;\ell)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
now $\tilde{p}_y(y;\ell)$ can be expressed in terms of the standard CDF.
Question
Unfortunately, $p_y(y;\ell)$ and $\tilde{p}_y(y;\ell)$ don't seem to be equivalent. I'm wondering where are the flaws in my methods and if, maybe, one of the two formulas for $p(y;\ell)$ is correct.
